# Listview doesn't display data when I run on real device(API 8) but displays when i run on emulater(API 16)

Tags: android-listview

Can anyone please tel me what can be the problem?

### *This is my code*

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_list);
        lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = fetchData();                                 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                       
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<String> users = parseJSON(data);                                                
                    }
                });   
            }
        }).start();

final SimpleAdapter adapter =
            new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.rowlayout,
                    row , new int[] {R.id.label,R.id.label1});
            lst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### **ERROR LOG**

05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3041)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:647)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:673)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5255)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:3774)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:6680)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:6805)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:906)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:611)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:514)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:74)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:85)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:280)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2798)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2671)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2646)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at com.example.book.ManageAuthor.parseJSON(ManageAuthor.java:198)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at com.example.book.ManageAuthor$1.run(ManageAuthor.java:77)
05-24 11:08:32.218: E/AndroidRuntime(19121):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable).

For example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.book_list);
    lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            data = fetchData();                                 
            lst.post(new Runnable() {                       
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<String> users = parseJSON(data);               
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.rowlayout, row , new int[] {R.id.label,R.id.label1});   
                    lst.setAdapter(adapter);                              
                }
            });   
        }
    }).start();
```

In that way you can parse the JSON data asynchronously and modify the data of the listview in a thread safe manner.

Comment: My app works fine on Emulator with API 16 but When I try to run it on emulator below API 16 it doesn't display data in listview and also it gives following exception. 

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray